# fails to deploy in WildFly

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, resteasy, wildfly

I came across a problem while trying to deploy a REST endpoint in WildFly. Specifically, I have a very simple app with one endpoint:

Project : https://github.com/CloudBees-community/wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart

When I deploy the very same app to WildFly (wildfly-8.2) using the "RUN" button in Eclipse I am getting the following exception:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".WeldStartService, JBAS014799: ... and 6 more ] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, JBAS014799: ... and 8 more ] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.VIEW."localdomain.localhost.CountryRepository".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.VIEW."localdomain.localhost.CountryResource".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.VIEW."localdomain.localhost.MyApplication".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".WeldStartService, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.START, JBAS014799: ... and 2 more ] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.app.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.env (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.BeanManager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.DefaultContextService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.DefaultDataSource (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.DefaultManagedExecutorService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.DefaultManagedThreadFactory (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.EJBContext (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.TimerService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UserTransaction (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.env (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.env."localdomain.localhost.CountryRepository".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.env."localdomain.localhost.CountryResource".countryRepository (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".jndiDependencyService, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryResource.START] 
  service jboss.persistenceunit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war#jpa-pu" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.CountryRepository.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".WeldStartService, service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.war".component.MyApplication.START, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
```

And web-app at: :8080/wildfly-restEasy-ejb-clickstart/ dont work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i had the same kind of error messages after restarting wildfly twice in Eclipse with the run button... I added through the management console a mysql driver (deployments). I believe when you click run in eclipse it however rewrites some default configuration, and make disappear files. In my case when I went back to the management console after restarting through eclipse the mysql driver was not anymore in the deployments section...

If i find a solution for this i will get back